# POST inputed data to the query string - php

Tags: php, query-string

Im trying to use the query string to pass data from page to page, i understnad how to pass the fixed data, ie if you clicked a button that would send you to page A and add a fixed query to the string.

But im unsure about how to get data from an input and place that in the query string.

Ive tried several approaches but couldnt get any of them to work any idea how i would do this ?

```
form action="index.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="link" placeholder="Paste" />

    <?php printf("<a class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary insert' href=\"about.php?url=%s\">%s</a>", $url, 'Insert'); ?> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

HTML

```
<form action="doWhatever.php" method="post" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Put your text here" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="enter" />
</form>
```

PHP (doWhatever.php)

```
<?php
  $input = $_POST["text"];
  header("Location: goWherever.php?" . http_build_query(array('text' -> $input)));
?>
```

I am assuming you want to load in a special way based on want the user inputs. And if that is the case might I suggest you use `session` variables instead of `GET` variables

Like this...

PHP (doWhatever.php)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["input"] = $_POST["text"];
  header("Location: goWherever.php");
?>
```

HTML (goWherever.php)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_SESSION["input"] == 'foobar'){
    //load the page one way
  }
  else{
  //load the page some other way
  }
  ?>
```